# Remove / Rename Uncategorized Category In Wordpress

Tags: categories

I have installed wordpress Muilit Site (NETWORK)

I need to Remove / Rename **`Uncategorized`** Category In Wordpress.

How is this possible?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To change the default "Uncategorized" using code you can do the following:

```
// Uncategorized ID is always 1
wp_update_term(1, 'category', array(
  'name' => 'hello',
  'slug' => 'hello', 
  'description' => 'hi'
));
```

Read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_term

Answer (score 1):

In `wp-admin`, you can rename the `Uncategorized` category any time. Just go to `Posts > Categories` and do it. :)

In case you forgot to assign a post to any category WordPress will add that post to `Uncategorized` by default. That's why a default category is must.

To change a default category go to `Settings > Writing`.

Then choose the Default category whatever you want; but you have to add a new category from the Categories page first. Enjoy WordPress.

Comment: i need to do it via php code because user will create the site when they need so i need to do it vai php code

Answer (score 0):

You can easily rename uncategorize category in WordPress. Just go to Posts the select Categories. Then click on Edit just below Uncategorized. Then enter your meaningful category. Finally, click on Update. That's all.

http://www.mytechgoal.com/rename-uncategorized-category-in-wordpress/